# Downloading and using a large number of avatars

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, swift3

I'm wondering if you can help me solve more of a general, process question.

In my app when the user signs up, I create a thumbnail avatar (approx 35x35 px). I upload this to the server.

In another section of my app I display all users in a UITableView. This table is populated by a request that occurs on the view controller beforehand (so I can reduce loading screens).

This table contains approximately 100 rows. My question is, how do I load all the avatars seamlessly?

- I dont want the user to tap the view and see a bunch of users, then avatars loading in randomly.
- I dont want a loading screen to appear, unless its absolutely necessary (i.e. the user navigates through the app quickly).
- I dont want to fire off 100 requests at once to my server.

I would like to send one request, and possibly get them back all at once. And if I did this, is there a specific format I should use? A big JSON response with base64 encoded thumbnails? :/

In addition to this, should I cache these? If so, how?

Swift 3.

Thanks!

Comment: use SDWebImage or AFImage, it can download only those user is appearing on the table view, then you can cache it and use for later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research based on Pratham Mehta's answer, I found a library called KingFisher:
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

This is more appropriate for my project, given SDWebImage is written in Objective-C, and my project is in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage is a really amazing framework that you can use to achieve this task. I've used it in every app of mine.

You can find it here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

You can just put the following code in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method

```
cell.imageView.sd_setImageWithURL(String.initWithURL("http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"))
```

The URL specified here is the link to the individual image to be shown in that particular row. This way your app can load images as the user scrolls the tableview. Given that your images are 35x35, it should be smooth and quick.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Nuke](https://github.com/kean/Nuke). It's designed to support large collections of images (has built-in throttling, rate limiting of requests, etc).

> And if I did this, is there a specific format I should use? A big JSON response with base64 encoded thumbnails? :/

I would suggest to avoid any premature optimizations - just download the images lazily one by one as soon as they appear on the display. Most image loading frameworks are designed to support this really well.

In addition you can [prefetch](https://kean.github.io/blog/image-preheating) the images.

If you want to do it the hard way - just zip the images and download the archive.

> In addition to this, should I cache these? If so, how?

You may find [this](https://kean.github.io/blog/image-caching) helpful.